# Remove gap between objects using CSS

Tags: html, css

Looking for a way to remove a gap between two objects. At the moment there is the container showing between my ul menu and the div that will hold my content. I have looked at changing margins/display but cannot figure out how to remove it.
Here is an image to show what I mean. I want to remove the gap between the black bar and the menubar.
Sorry for horrrid CSS question. :>

IMAGE:https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLgxk.png

Pastebin Ids (put them at the end of pastebin url.)

CSS: /iUadQRK0

HTML: /ShWXsp8v

Cheers for any help in advance xx

Comment: Have you try `margin: 0;` in your target elements?

Comment: Insert your `HTML` and `CSS` here, or make a jsFiddle.

Comment: [jsFiddle for fiddling](http://jsfiddle.net/3D8aq/)

Comment: Remove your #menu { height: 25px; } ...

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie, you are right. +1. I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: Worked Alexandre. Cheers. xx

Comment: Note: if your question already have a correct answer please accept it! so that member know that! question already have correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

As answered in comments, you should remove the height on the UL element :

```
#menu
{
    height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to remove height, set float:left; to ul element like

```
#menu{
        float:left;
        width:100%;    
        height:25px;
        background-color: #0000FF;
        margin:0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type:none;
}
```

Also you can check out this page, if you want to learn how alignment works.
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-alignment.php

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove height from #menu.

```
#menu{
    width:100%;    
   /* height:25px; */
    background-color: #0000FF;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```